# Animation not working in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a button and a collection view (horizontal) inside keyboard input view. Auto Layout is used. The button is hidden by default using Leading Constraint set to -50. When user start using collection view and **contentOffset.x** of collection view is greater than 80, The button will show. The code is working fine but animation is not working.

```
extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if self.collectionView.contentOffset.x > 80 {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
                self.sideButtonLeadingConstraint.constant = 0
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)
        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
                self.sideButtonLeadingConstraint.constant = -50
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: project link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5UHWsK1E6dSTFh4ZDJxMmxpYUE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you shouldn't change you constraints inside animations block. Second, `scrollViewDidScroll` method is called a large number of times, and you should set some limitations for calling animation code inside it. Try something like this:

```
extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let needsShow = collectionView.contentOffset.x > 80 && sideButtonLeadingConstraint.constant != 0
        let needsHide = collectionView.contentOffset.x <= 80 && sideButtonLeadingConstraint.constant != -50

        if needsShow {
            sideButtonLeadingConstraint.constant = 0                
        } else if needsHide {
            sideButtonLeadingConstraint.constant = -50
        }

        if needsShow || needsHide {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not working https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5UHWsK1E6dSTFh4ZDJxMmxpYUE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: you should call `self.photoView.layoutIfNeeded()` instead of `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` in your case

Answer (score 1):

Try as follows by updating the constant outside the animation block. It will do the update with animation effect.

```
extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if self.collectionView.contentOffset.x > 80 {
        self.sideButtonLeadingConstraint.constant = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        self.sideButtonLeadingConstraint.constant = -50
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}}
```

Comment: Try UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: { self.view.layoutIfNeeded() }) instead of specfic animation type.

Comment: The same code is working fine for me, Are you sure you have right constraints for the sideButton ? Make sure the sideButton has no trailing constraint. If doubt on the constraint, clear the constraint and re construct the constraint and try again.

Comment: I think I have right constraints. I've created a small project of this problem. Here's the link. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5UHWsK1E6dSTFh4ZDJxMmxpYUE/view?usp=sharing